# Development storage not shown in Cloud Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-storage-emulator

This week I re-installed my development PC and now I'm missing the local development storage in Cloud Explorer (storage emulator is running). There is only Data Lake Analytics now, which I don't need.

[image]

This has always been working fine, much better than the separate Storage Explorer tool, because in that tool you always had to log in to an existing  Azure subscription before you could select development storage. 
Is there maybe some component of VS2017 missing that needs to be installed?

Comment: See answer below, apparently it was a bug that existed for a while in version 1.2.18x.x  The issue is fixed in current version 1.2.1810.253

Answer (score 3):

Under Investigation - "Reverting to 1.2.1806.2915 does indeed work."

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/335015/cloud-explorer-not-shoing-development-storage.html

Comment: You would be good? :) Well, full history is under the link above. I think it's better to keep all descriptions in one place as they have tendencies to quickly become obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's still not fixed in 1.2.1809 though

Comment: The issue is fixed in current version 1.2.1810.253!